# User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization is missing from the list of timer jobs

Tags: user-profile, profile-sync, user

'User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization' and 'User Profile to SharePoint Quick Synchronization' are missing from my list of available timer jobs.  The User Profile Service is configured, Sync is configured and sync is working effectively with no errors in FIM.  Has anyone seen this before?

[image]

Comment: What happens when you create a seperate User Profile Service Application? Are you using the default service application association?

Comment: If I create a new User Profile Service Application, all the timer jobs appear as expected.  The jacked up service application is in the default proxy group.  It seems that I'll just have to recreate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by my comment, you may need to recreate the service application...